# Credit Card expiry date validation using javax.validation constraints or annotations

Tags: java, rest, validation, constraints, javax

I have a REST API that takes credit card information as input and processes it. I am using various javax.validation annotations such as @NotNull for validating the mandatory data.

How can I validate the expiry date on a credit card?

Note: Credit Card expiry date does NOT contain date. It contains only month and year. Example: 12/17 which means that the card is expiring in Dec 2107.

```
public class CreditCardData {

    @NotNull
    private Long cardNo

    @NotNull
    //WHAT ANNOTATION SHOULD I PUT HERE SO THAT IT IS FUTURE DATE ?????
    //WILL CONTAIN ONLY MON/YY, EXAMPLE: 12/17
    private String expiryDate

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a ready-made annotation that validates card expirations, but it's quite easy to create your own.

Create your annotation:

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CardExpirationValidator.class)
public static @interface CardExpiration {
    String message() default "Expiration invalid";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Note the `javax.validation.Constraint` annotation - it says that the CardExpiration annotation is a constraint validated by another class - `CardExpirationValidator.class`. So let's go ahead and write that class with our validation logic. It's going to be something like this:

```
public static class CardExpirationValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CardExpiration, String> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(CardExpiration annotation) {
        //Not much to do - this is invoked before "isValid", and can be used to pass annotation parameters
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        //Insert validation logic for "value" here. Return true/false
    }
}
```

Now you can annotate parameters and fields like this:

```
public class CreditCardData {

    @NotNull
    private Long cardNo;

    @NotNull
    @CardExpiration
    private String expiryDate;
}
```

See [Jersey](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html#d0e13779)'s/[JBoss](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-constraintannotation)'s documentation on the topic.